# I want to extract the tag name using sql from table with XML stored as clob. (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, parsing, clob

Sample XML as below:

```
<Root>
...
<XMLNSC>
...
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
...
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<typesNS0:getABCD xmlns:typesNS0="http://xxx.xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/x/" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
```

last tag typesNS0:getABCD want to select

Comment: could you write correct xml and tag which you want to extract?

Comment: of course i do.

Comment: I know how to select value with EXTRACVALUE command, but i dont know how to select tag

Comment: just use EXTRACT function

Answer (score 0):

```
select xmltype(a).extract('//typesNS0:getABCD','xmlns:typesNS0="http://xxx.xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/x/"')
from (
  select 
  '<Root xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://a.b.org/">
    <XMLNSC />
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body/>
    <typesNS0:getABCD xmlns:typesNS0="http://xxx.xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/x/" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">123</typesNS0:getABCD>
  </Root>' a from dual
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may run below script if you want get exact tag value;

```
DECLARE
vs_Xml VARCHAR2(32000):= '<Root xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://a.b.org/">
<XMLNSC />
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body/>
<typesNS0:getABCD xmlns:typesNS0="http://xxx.xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/x/"    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">123</typesNS0:getABCD>
</Root>';

vx_ParameterList   XMLTYPE;
vx_Parameter       XMLTYPE;
vn_ParameterIndex  NUMBER;
vs_Key             VARCHAR2(64);
vs_XPath           VARCHAR2(255);
vs_Value           VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN
vx_ParameterList := xmltype(vs_Xml);
vn_ParameterIndex := 1;
vs_XPath := '/Root'; 

WHILE vx_ParameterList.existsNode(vs_XPath || '[' || vn_ParameterIndex || ']') = 1 LOOP
vx_Parameter := vx_ParameterList.extract(vs_XPath || '[' || vn_ParameterIndex || ']');

 vs_Value := vx_Parameter.extract('//typesNS0:getABCD/text()','xmlns:typesNS0="http://xxx.xx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/x/"').GetStringVal();
vn_ParameterIndex := vn_ParameterIndex + 1;

dbms_output.put_line(vs_Value);
END LOOP;

END;
```